# Google Sheets: Arrayformula for summarizing textjoined arrays (query/filter...)

Tags: google-sheets, automation, google-sheets-formula, formula, array-formulas

I have a problem in Google Sheets summarizing values from a column in one single cell using an Arrayformula.

I made an easy example how my data looks like (approximately) and how I want to summarize it.
In table1 you can see project_members stuffed on different projects.
Table2 shows how I want to visualize my data. In column D the unique project_ids are listed, so far so good. Now I want column E to show every member stuffed on the project I can find next to them.

[Example][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1v1mk.png

I have managed to get what I want using this:

=TEXTJOIN(" , ";1;FILTER(B:B;A:A=D2))

or

=TEXTJOIN(" , ";1;QUERY(A:D;"Select B where A contains '"& D2 &"' ";0))

Now my actual dataset is way bigger than this example and data is beeing added constantly. This is why I need the formula in column E to be automated.
I have tried this:

=ARRAYFORMULA(TEXTJOIN(" , ";1;QUERY(A:D;"Select B where A contains '"& D:D &"' ";0)))

But that doesnt work.
I´m thankful for help!

Comment: Please share a link to your spreadsheet, a copy of it, or a dummy spreadsheet with some realistic data in it. Whichever you choose, please indicate where you want results to show (though I recommend that you have results appear in their own sheet).

Comment: Hey Erik, here is the link to a dummy version:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_HZa2r2L7Wn5IO2nO1i8ZUytwHhmU_b3tg4qSy0Z_tQ/edit?usp=sharing

In my real application I want the results to appear in a different sheet, but that should be irrelevant in this case, as I just need a working solution in general before adjusting the formulas to my needs :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### solution

Try this unique arrayformula that will take into account added lines (German Notation)

```
=ARRAY_CONSTRAIN( transpose({transpose(unique(A2:A));arrayformula(trim(query(arrayformula(if(A2:A=transpose(unique(A2:A));B2:B&",";));;9^9)))});counta(unique(A2:A));2)
```

[image]

### explanation about the construction

the most important step is in D2 (US notation)`=arrayformula(if(A2:A10=transpose(unique(A2:A10)),B2:B10,))`, then apply query(,,9*9) to gather all items in each column

[image]

Comment: Hey Mike, thank you for replying.
Problem is, that projects are getting added constantly and a more dynamic solution is needed. 
I would like to have one single (Array)formula, which generates the results for the whole column automatically without refering to a static range.

Comment: I apologize for misunderstanding but yes it is already the case .I will clarify my answer. Ich entschuldige mich für das Missverständnis, aber ja, das ist bereits der Fall. Ich werde meine Antwort präzisieren.

Comment: Thanks Mike! Your formula works also!

Comment: To answer your question, 9^9 that I use alse is the third argument of query. It means that the header of the result of query function will take 9^9 rows of data !! that means the totality ... this is a trick to merge or join all the items in ech column.

Answer (score 0):

See my newly added sheet ("Erik Help") and this formula there:

`=ArrayFormula({A1:B1;REGEXREPLACE(TRIM(SPLIT(FLATTEN(QUERY(QUERY({A2:A&"~"\B2:B&","};  "Select MAX(Col2) where Col2 IS NOT NULL GROUP BY Col2 PIVOT Col1");; 9^9));"~"));"[,\s]+$";"")})`

This formula is complex, and so I invite anyone who is interested to take it apart and put it back together for understanding.

Comment: Hey Erik! Thanks a lot! That works really good!
The formula is pretty complex and I dont understand the "9^9" part, but it does its job.

Comment: Whenever you see `9^9` in a formula, it's just a generally accepted way of saying "a really high number" or "more than you will ever need." Your small example would have worked just the same if you replaced `9^9` with `10`; but since your final number of elements is unknown, `9^9` assures that you'll be covered. If you feel better, change it to a number that's more than the maximum number of rows you'll ever try to process with the formula, and it should be fine.